# What happens when files are added/removed in the middle of a "for f in *" sh loop?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, for

I found one for loop example online. Now I want to use it in my code but I am not sure how does this loop operates

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/* 
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Now I want to ask that

1. Does it look in search_dir in each iteration and  copies files in search_dir to entry variable one file in each iteration?
2. Or I take a snapshot of all the contents of search_dir and then store that snapshot to entry variable?
3. Is there any change in output if some one inserts some file in search_dir while the loop is still working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the shell gets to the `for`-statement, it will expand the value of `$search_dir` and perform the file name globbing to generate a list of directory entries that will be iterated over. This happens only once, and if the things in `$search_dir` disappears or if there are new files/directories added to that directory while the loop is executing, these changes will not be picked up.

If the loop operates on the directory entries whose names are in `$entry`, one might want to test for their existence in the loop, especially if the loop is known to take a long time to run and there are lots of files that are in constant flux for one reason or another:

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/*; do
    if [ -e "$entry" ]; then
        # operate on "$entry"
    else
        # handle the case that "$entry" went away
    fi
done
```

As Stéphane rightly points out in comments, this is a superfluous test in *most* cases.

Comment: In any case the file may still disappear in between the `[ -e ]` and the `operate` so that additional check doesn't necessarily add more.

Comment: Is it necessary to put a ; in first statement after "$search_dir"/* because I am observing that the code is still working fine even without a semicolon.?

Comment: @unixbeginner If you put the `do` on the same line as the `for`, yes.  Semicolons may almost always be replaced by newlines in the shell syntax.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That depends on the length of the operation and the number of entries iterated over.  If it takes hours to run the loop, it may be prudent to have the test there. Yes, there is always a risk that the entry disappears between the test and the subsequent operation.

Comment: Stéphane what do you mean by [ -e ] or operate please make clear once again

Comment: @unixbeginner He points out that if the loop runs quickly, the test for existence is more or less useless, and that `$entry` may technically be deleted in-between the test for existence and the subsequent operation on that file/directory (which is always an issue).

Comment: @unixbeginner, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Comment: So as explained by Stéphane to avoid entry variable from any modifications while loop is working should I put a sleep of  1 or 2 sec inside loop. Will it be good enough to avoid $entry to change between loop processing

Comment: @unixbeginner The value of `$entry` is not the issue. It's whether it refers to something that actually exists or not.  It would have existed when the `for` statement executed, but the list that we iterate over is static from that point (and I don't know what other processes are handling the files in the directory you're looking at). I'm not sure what you would achieve from inserting `sleep` statements. I think you have misunderstood something.

Comment: Ok so you want to say that loop will provide unexpected result if some one removes files from search_dir while loop is processing.

Comment: See also the `3< "$entry" operate /dev/fd/3` if it's important that the file exists at the time `operate` attempts to open() it (note that on systems other than Linux, that also prevents `operate` from opening the file in write mode).

Comment: @unixbeginner Unexpected in the sense that that if a file goes away, it will still be iterated over, since the generated list of files is static.

Comment: Ok so is there any way to make sure that files remain at their place while loop is still working.

Comment: @unixbeginner Um, don't mess with the stuff in that directory while the script is running? I have no idea of what context you are asking this in. It may be a private little script made to run in your home directory on a laptop, or it may be made to run in a high throughput production environment with thousands of other processes competing for resources and wanting to create and delete files all the time.

Comment: Yes first of all the are only PDFs and .ind files in search_dir there is no sub directory inside search_dir and no one is going to remove the files from there but there is a program which will be running parallel to this shell code that will add some more files inside search_dir during loop is working. Is there any possibility that those new files will also be processed by this for loop?

Comment: @unixbeginner Those new files would not be processed by this loop.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda,@Stéphane Chazelas for your suggestions.

Comment: @kusalananda is there any possibility that wild card used after $searchdir will not work in case there is a huge amount of files in search_dir.

Comment: @unixbeginner That would be the case if you used `utility *` and `utility` was an external utility. Here, the shell does not need to call `execve()`, so it won't hit the limit imposed by `execve()` on the command line length by executing an external utility.

Comment: @Kusalananda that means this loop should work fine even if there are more than 10 lac files in search_dir since above code doesn't use any utility

Answer (score 1):

The shell fully determines the list of values to loop on before it starts running the loop body. That is:

1. The shell builds a path using value of the variable `search_dir`.
2. The shell collects the list of file names in the specified directory, to build the list of matches for the wildcard pattern.
3. The shell executes the loop body, in turn, with each element of the list of matches.

You can change the value of the variable `search_dir`, and change the content of the directory, while the loop is running. This won't affect what files the loop acts on.

If a file is removed while the loop is processing other files, then once it gets to that file, that file won't exist. Depending on what you do in the loop, it may or may not matter. If there is a concurrent process that may remove files, note that testing whether the file exists before processing it won't really solve that problem, since [the file could be removed between the time you test and the time you start processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

If you need to mark a file as processed to make sure that you don't process it twice, then this script should move the files to another directory once it's processed them. Moving a file to another directory (on the same filesystem) is [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)): either it isn't done yet or it's done, there's no intermediate state. But once again, if a *different* process (possibly another instance of that scripts) moves files, then the loop will sometimes hit files that are moved while the loop is executing.

If you want to process new files as they are created, then you'll need to loop again. Obviously files could be created during the execution of the loop, or after all the prior files have been processed, so the script would need to keep running forever. There are tools to wait until a file is created in a directory. On Linux, the basic facility for that is [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify); if you need to process files as they are created, then [`inotifywait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html) or [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) should help you. Remember that inotify only notifies you of files created (or modified or accessed depending on your trigger) *after* the inotify-based commands start; you'll also need to take care of prior existing files, and you can't just do `for entry in *; do …; done; inotifywait …` because files can be created during the execution of the loop or even while the `inotifywait` command is starting up.

Comment: @giles is there any possibility that this loop will not work in case there are huge amount of files present in $searchdir since we are using wildcard *

Comment: @unixbeginner The number of files isn't a problem. The list of file names only has to fit in memory, it doesn't have to fit in a command line length limit like `somecommand *` would.

Comment: currently I am observing that when no. of files in search_dir exceeds over 2 lac it show too many arguments error is there any other way to solve this issue

Comment: @unixbeginner The snippet you posted in the question would not show this message in bash. If you have another problem, ask a new question, with a complete script.

Comment: that means this loop should work fine even there is more than 10 lac files in search_dir since i am not using wildcard with somecommand as you mentioned above in one of your comment